# How to avoid circular slider?

Tags: html

I have done the following carousel slider in this slider after reached to the last album it again shows me the first image .I just wanted to avoid that circular slider. When it reach at the end album image it does not show the first image. Thanks in advance.
index.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico"> 
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        </head>
        <body>

        <div class="container">


                <div id="ca-container" class="ca-container">
                    <div class="ca-wrapper">
                        <div class="ca-item ca-item-1">
                            <!--<div class="ca-item-main"> -->
                                <img src="/Users/vivekbhintade/Downloads/CircularContentCarousel/images/animal1.png"/>
                            <!--</div> -->

                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-item ca-item-2">

                                <img src="/Users/vivekbhintade/Downloads/CircularContentCarousel/images/animal2.png"/>


                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-item ca-item-3">

                                                    <img src="/Users/vivekbhintade/Downloads/CircularContentCarousel/images/animal3.png"/>


                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-item ca-item-4">

                                <img src="/Users/vivekbhintade/Downloads/CircularContentCarousel/images/animal4.png"/>


                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-item ca-item-5">

                                        <img src="/Users/vivekbhintade/Downloads/CircularContentCarousel/images/animal5.png"/>

                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-item ca-item-6">

                                <img src="/Users/vivekbhintade/Downloads/CircularContentCarousel/images/animal6.png"/>


                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
            <!-- the jScrollPane script -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.contentcarousel.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('#ca-container').contentcarousel();
            </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

style.css

```
    /* Circular Content Carousel Style */
.ca-container{
    position:relative;
    margin:25px auto 20px auto;
    width:597px;
    height:150px;
}
.ca-wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    position:relative;
}
.ca-item{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
.ca-more{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right:0px;
    padding:4px 15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background: #ccbda2;
    text-align:center;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Georgia","Times New Roman",serif;
    font-style:italic;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #897c63;
}
.ca-close{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    right:10px;
    background:#fff url(../images/cross.png) no-repeat center center;
    width:27px;
    height:27px;
    text-indent:-9000px;
    outline:none;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    opacity:0.7;
}
.ca-close:hover{
    opacity:1.0;
}
.ca-item-main{
    padding:20px;
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
    right:5px;
    bottom:5px;
    background:#fff;
    overflow:hidden;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.ca-icon{
    width:233px;
    height:189px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:transparent url(../images/animal1.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.ca-item-2 .ca-icon{
    background-image:url(../images/animal2.png);
}
.ca-item-3 .ca-icon{
    background-image:url(../images/animal3.png);
}
.ca-item-4 .ca-icon{
    background-image:url(../images/animal4.png);
}
.ca-item-5 .ca-icon{
    background-image:url(../images/animal5.png);
}
.ca-item-6 .ca-icon{
    background-image:url(../images/animal6.png);
}

.ca-item h3{
    font-family: 'Coustard', sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:30px;
    color:#000;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    height:85px;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #e4ebe9;
}
.ca-item h4{
    font-family: "Georgia","Times New Roman",serif;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:left;
    border-left:10px solid #b0ccc6;
    padding-left:10px;
    line-height:24px;
    margin:10px;
    position:relative;
}
.ca-item h4 span{
    text-indent:40px;
    display:block;
}
.ca-item h4  span.ca-quote{
    color:#f4eee3;
    font-size:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:0px;
    text-indent:0px;
}
.ca-content-wrapper{
    background:#b0ccc6;
    position:absolute;
    width:0px; /* expands to width of the wrapper minus 1 element */
    height:440px;
    top:5px;
    text-align:left;
    z-index:10000;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.ca-content{
    width:660px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.ca-content-text{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: "Georgia","Times New Roman",serif;
    margin:10px 20px;
    padding:10px 20px;
    line-height:24px;
}
.ca-content-text p{
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
.ca-content h6{
    margin:25px 20px 0px 35px;
    font-size:32px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    color:#000;
    font-family: 'Coustard', sans-serif;
    color:#60817a;
    border-bottom:2px solid #99bcb4;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #99BCB4;
}
.ca-content ul{
    margin:20px 35px;
    height:30px;
}
.ca-content ul li{
    float:left;
    margin:0px 2px;
}
.ca-content ul li a{
    color:#fff;
    background:#000;
    padding:3px 6px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family: "Georgia","Times New Roman",serif;
    font-style:italic;
}
.ca-content ul li a:hover{
    background:#fff;
    color:#000;
    text-shadow:none;
}
.ca-nav span{
    width:25px;
    height:38px;
    background:transparent url(../images/arrows.png) no-repeat top left;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-19px;
    left:-40px;
    text-indent:-9000px;
    opacity:0.7;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:100;
}
.ca-nav span.ca-nav-next{
    background-position:top right;
    left:auto;
    right:-40px;
}
.ca-nav span:hover{
    opacity:1.0;
}
```

jquery.contentcarousel.js

```
(function($) {
    var aux     = {
            // navigates left / right
            navigate    : function( dir, $el, $wrapper, opts, cache ) {

                var scroll      = opts.scroll,
                    factor      = 1,
                    idxClicked  = 0;

                if( cache.expanded ) {
                    scroll      = 1; // scroll is always 1 in full mode
                    factor      = 3; // the width of the expanded item will be 3 times bigger than 1 collapsed item 
                    idxClicked  = cache.idxClicked; // the index of the clicked item
                }

                // clone the elements on the right / left and append / prepend them according to dir and scroll
                if( dir === 1 ) {
                    $wrapper.find('div.ca-item:lt(' + scroll + ')').each(function(i) {
                        $(this).clone(true).css( 'left', ( cache.totalItems - idxClicked + i ) * cache.itemW * factor + 'px' ).appendTo( $wrapper );
                    });
                }
                else {
                    var $first  = $wrapper.children().eq(0);

                    $wrapper.find('div.ca-item:gt(' + ( cache.totalItems  - 1 - scroll ) + ')').each(function(i) {
                        // insert before $first so they stay in the right order
                        $(this).clone(true).css( 'left', - ( scroll - i + idxClicked ) * cache.itemW * factor + 'px' ).insertBefore( $first );
                    });
                }

                // animate the left of each item
                // the calculations are dependent on dir and on the cache.expanded value
                $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').each(function(i) {
                    var $item   = $(this);
                    $item.stop().animate({
                        left    :  ( dir === 1 ) ? '-=' + ( cache.itemW * factor * scroll ) + 'px' : '+=' + ( cache.itemW * factor * scroll ) + 'px'
                    }, opts.sliderSpeed, opts.sliderEasing, function() {
                        if( ( dir === 1 && $item.position().left < - idxClicked * cache.itemW * factor ) || ( dir === -1 && $item.position().left > ( ( cache.totalItems - 1 - idxClicked ) * cache.itemW * factor ) ) ) {
                            // remove the item that was cloned
                            $item.remove();
                        }                       
                        cache.isAnimating   = false;
                    });
                });

            },
            // opens an item (animation) -> opens all the others
            openItem    : function( $wrapper, $item, opts, cache ) {
                cache.idxClicked    = $item.index();
                // the item's position (1, 2, or 3) on the viewport (the visible items) 
                cache.winpos        = aux.getWinPos( $item.position().left, cache );                
                $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').not( $item ).hide();
                $item.find('div.ca-content-wrapper').css( 'left', cache.itemW + 'px' ).stop().animate({
                    width   : cache.itemW * 2 + 'px',
                    left    : cache.itemW + 'px'
                }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing)
                .end()
                .stop()
                .animate({
                    left    : '0px'
                }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing, function() {
                    cache.isAnimating   = false;
                    cache.expanded      = true;

                    aux.openItems( $wrapper, $item, opts, cache );
                });

            },
            // opens all the items
            openItems   : function( $wrapper, $openedItem, opts, cache ) {
                var openedIdx   = $openedItem.index();

                $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').each(function(i) {
                    var $item   = $(this),
                        idx     = $item.index();

                    if( idx !== openedIdx ) {
                        $item.css( 'left', - ( openedIdx - idx ) * ( cache.itemW * 3 ) + 'px' ).show().find('div.ca-content-wrapper').css({
                            left    : cache.itemW + 'px',
                            width   : cache.itemW * 2 + 'px'
                        });

                        // hide more link
                        aux.toggleMore( $item, false );
                    }
                });
            },
            // show / hide the item's more button
            toggleMore  : function( $item, show ) {
                ( show ) ? $item.find('a.ca-more').show() : $item.find('a.ca-more').hide(); 
            },
            // close all the items
            // the current one is animated
            closeItems  : function( $wrapper, $openedItem, opts, cache ) {
                var openedIdx   = $openedItem.index();

                $openedItem.find('div.ca-content-wrapper').stop().animate({
                    width   : '0px'
                }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing)
                .end()
                .stop()
                .animate({
                    left    : cache.itemW * ( cache.winpos - 1 ) + 'px'
                }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing, function() {
                    cache.isAnimating   = false;
                    cache.expanded      = false;
                });

                // show more link
                aux.toggleMore( $openedItem, true );

                $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').each(function(i) {
                    var $item   = $(this),
                        idx     = $item.index();

                    if( idx !== openedIdx ) {
                        $item.find('div.ca-content-wrapper').css({
                            width   : '0px'
                        })
                        .end()
                        .css( 'left', ( ( cache.winpos - 1 ) - ( openedIdx - idx ) ) * cache.itemW + 'px' )
                        .show();

                        // show more link
                        aux.toggleMore( $item, true );
                    }
                });
            },
            // gets the item's position (1, 2, or 3) on the viewport (the visible items)
            // val is the left of the item
            getWinPos   : function( val, cache ) {
                switch( val ) {
                    case 0                  : return 1; break;
                    case cache.itemW        : return 2; break;
                    case cache.itemW * 2    : return 3; break;
                }
            }
        },
        methods = {
            init        : function( options ) {

                if( this.length ) {

                    var settings = {
                        sliderSpeed     : 500,          // speed for the sliding animation
                        sliderEasing    : 'easeOutExpo',// easing for the sliding animation
                        itemSpeed       : 500,          // speed for the item animation (open / close)
                        itemEasing      : 'easeOutExpo',// easing for the item animation (open / close)
                        scroll          : 1             // number of items to scroll at a time
                    };

                    return this.each(function() {

                        // if options exist, lets merge them with our default settings
                        if ( options ) {
                            $.extend( settings, options );
                        }

                        var $el             = $(this),
                            $wrapper        = $el.find('div.ca-wrapper'),
                            $items          = $wrapper.children('div.ca-item'),
                            cache           = {};

                        // save the with of one item    
                        cache.itemW         = $items.width();
                        // save the number of total items
                        cache.totalItems    = $items.length;

                        // add navigation buttons
                        if( cache.totalItems > 3 )  
                            $el.prepend('<div class="ca-nav"><span class="ca-nav-prev">Previous</span><span class="ca-nav-next">Next</span></div>') 

                        // control the scroll value
                        if( settings.scroll < 1 )
                            settings.scroll = 1;
                        else if( settings.scroll > 3 )
                            settings.scroll = 3;    

                        var $navPrev        = $el.find('span.ca-nav-prev'),
                            $navNext        = $el.find('span.ca-nav-next');

                        // hide the items except the first 3
                        $wrapper.css( 'overflow', 'hidden' );

                        // the items will have position absolute 
                        // calculate the left of each item
                        $items.each(function(i) {
                            $(this).css({
                                position    : 'absolute',
                                left        : i * cache.itemW + 'px',
                                marginLeft  : i * 5 + 'px'
                            });
                        });

                        // click to open the item(s)
                        $el.find('a.ca-more').live('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                            if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                            cache.isAnimating   = true;
                            $(this).hide();
                            var $item   = $(this).closest('div.ca-item');
                            aux.openItem( $wrapper, $item, settings, cache );
                            return false;
                        });

                        // click to close the item(s)
                        $el.find('a.ca-close').live('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                            if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                            cache.isAnimating   = true;
                            var $item   = $(this).closest('div.ca-item');
                            aux.closeItems( $wrapper, $item, settings, cache );
                            return false;
                        });

                        // navigate left
                        $navPrev.bind('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                            if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                            cache.isAnimating   = true;
                            aux.navigate( -1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                        });

                        // navigate right
                        $navNext.bind('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                            if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                            cache.isAnimating   = true;
                            aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                        });

                        // adds events to the mouse
                        $el.bind('mousewheel.contentcarousel', function(e, delta) {
                            if(delta > 0) {
                                if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                                cache.isAnimating   = true;
                                aux.navigate( -1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                            }   
                            else {
                                if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                                cache.isAnimating   = true;
                                aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                            }   
                            return false;
                        });

                    });
                }
            }
        };

    $.fn.contentcarousel = function(method) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.contentcarousel' );
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: fiddle your code..That would make it easier to resolve your problem..

Comment: Its very diffucult to fiddle it because i dont know where is the problem.

Comment: you dont have to know where is the problem to fiddle your code..Just fiddle it..